# Sites unavailable, intermittent behaviour

Tags: discussion, support, maintenance

Sites failing to update when refreshed, going to "Service unavailable" screen.

[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions), [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions), [Sci-Fi and Fantasy,](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) [Medical](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions), [Psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions).

Worldbuilding being an exception went to an "Oops, something bad happened" screen (I was refreshing a [particular question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/233770/what-could-be-a-good-example-of-a-massive-make-work-porgram-in-a-post-scarcity-s#233770)).

Main meta has so-far been fine.

I noticed this a few (~15) minutes ago, repeated refreshing a few minutes apart leads to sometimes the error message, sometimes the correct page.

[Stack-Status report](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/9cbac2e1-6bdc-41c9-b520-8875d3ce5050):

> August 03, 2022 | 02:45PM (01:45 PM UTC) Stack Exchange Network Sites has
> transitioned to Unavailable

Then:

> August 03, 2022 | 03:13PM (02:13 PM UTC) Stack Exchange Network Sites has
> transitioned to Degraded

Something seems up on SE's end, not just local to here, southern UK.

Comment: Was just about to ask.  My VPN endpoint (NE USA) is seeing the same, so it's not local to you.  Also, it's a bit random; I hit the top 4 links in HNQ and 2 of them loaded, 2 of them got unavailable.

Comment: I have just experienced similar behavior in western Canada, so I assume it's on SE's end. Also, there's a current (as of about 15 minutes ago) [Stack Exchange status incident report](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/9cbac2e1-6bdc-41c9-b520-8875d3ce5050) about this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks, I'll add that.

Comment: There's something very big ongoing for a long time now. SE doing their best, with the best possible people, to fight it. Let's wish them luck.

Comment: This is on SE's end, definitely. Has been happening on and off for a couple of days now.

Comment: [**Update**](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/9cbac2e1-6bdc-41c9-b520-8875d3ce5050): Stack Exchange Network Sites has transitioned to ***Degraded***.

Comment: I don't think we need to edit it with current status; The question was posted, goal is getting official response explaining what's going on.

Comment: Fair enough, that's as far as it needs to go. Leaving as-is for now unless something stupendous happens. @ShadowTheKidWizard

Comment: Well if something stupendous would happen, we won't be able to edit anyway. ;)

Comment: **Note:** For anybody interested, I believe the [Recent site instability, major outages – July/August 2022](/q/381161) post, since it's about an instability that started on July 29, 2022, has information that is applicable to this post.

Answer (score -3):

The image below from stackstatus.net is: Not precisely true.

DIY.se and this site (at least, I didn't bother to check any others) went to read only less than an hour ago, then came back after some minutes of outage.

[image]

Comment: No site has 100% uptime. Incidents are reported and logged only if they affect the site for more than few minutes.

Comment: ...but if you define *a few minutes* properly, 100% (reported) is easy to achieve, I guess. *"The clothes of the emperor are most exquisitely fine!"*