# How do we draw attention to our bug reports?

Tags: discussion, meta, bug-reports

I posted [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380934). It got ~35 views and 6 upvotes within a couple days of posting it. But then, people stopped viewing the question, and it hasn't really gotten any views or signs that the staff might fix it. How can I draw attention to my bug report, or possibly get the bug fixed?

Comment: From Shadow Wizard's comment below [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380959/sites-unavailable-intermittent-behaviour) (my) post, I gather they may be busy coping with some or other crisis/situation.

Comment: Your question has fallen off the site's home page, so you're unlikely to get more votes or views. You now have to wait [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514).

Comment: If you expect a reaction from staff within 2 days ... you clearly have to adjust your expectations. Especially for a non-urgent bug like that.

Comment: Apparently posting a meta about it not getting enough attention works... A member of staff added it to status-review

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators have a [way to escalate bug reports/feature requests to staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/622284), so they *could* escalate it for you, but... As Glorfindel said, you need to adjust your expectations a bit. Your bug report, while valid, is relatively minor and has only a few upvotes. It isn't really a good candidate for escalation. Moderators typically try to reserve escalation via [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for bug reports when they directly affect a newly-released feature, or the bug report is a somewhat major break in functionality. I recognize that this bug really bothers *you*, but the developers are quite busy and really should only switch focus to newly-made bug reports when they're serious enough to warrant immediate attention.

Some of the SE developers, and the SE community team, will sometimes go through older bug reports to triage them to be added to the developers' backlog to be fixed. Whether that time comes for your bug report now, years from now, or never is impossible to tell, but it's always a possibility.

So... Thank you for reporting a bug with the site, but try to recognize that the developers are perpetually busy and have a schedule they're likely not keen to disrupt for non-breaking bugs.

Answer (score 7):

On this meta, you can draw attention to any question by [placing a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on it. It's not forced to work though as the developers aren't always motivated by bounties. What it might do is result in someone posting a workaround or your question getting more votes. The former might be useful to you, the latter might attract the attention of developers if they thought that it meant that more people were affected or interested in a fix.

The reality is however that a few bug reports have had upvotes in the low hundreds and 6 upvotes doesn't really compete with those. This is a pretty cosmetic issue that you've found a work for yourself i.e. by refreshing the page.